# Can we add a The Battle Cats tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I have quite a few questions about The Battle Cats and I wish there was a tag for The Battle Cats so I could post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any user with 300+ rep can create a tag.  However, there needs to be a question for that tag to be used on.  So, ask your question and apply a tag that semi-works (such as [android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android)).  Then, a user with enough rep can go edit the question and add the [battle-cats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battle-cats) tag.

Comment: k, i might try and get 300 rep myself or ask some1. ty